# To pass the "rowcount" (Table Row Count) from jquery to "For Loop" (@for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)) inside the .CSHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

In MVC5, I tried to add/remove rows with glyphicon. I want to pass the "rowcount" (Table Row Count) from jquery to "For Loop" (@for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)) inside the .CSHTML.

Please refer the image which I tried to achieve.

[image: Adding rows dynamically and store the value in controller]

**Script:**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('.glyphicon-plus').click(function () {
        var sds = $(this);
        $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo('#ruleTable');
        var **rowCount** = $('#ruleTable tr').length;
    });
    $('.glyphicon-remove').click(function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

**HTML.BeginForm :**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++){
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" stye="color:lawngreen"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="color:red"></span>
        </td>
        <td> @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].DepartmentCode") </td>
        <td> @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].DepartmentName")</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: jQuery runs on the client and your `for` loop is in C# which runs on the server. The two cannot communicate directly. You will need to send an AJAX request with the rowCount, but you'll need to re-think your page structure for that to work. *However*, I don't see why you need to send the value from the client at all when the server already generated the rows, so therefore must already know how many there are...?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment...I added the image which I tried to achieve.

Comment: Please provide any suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Its Not Possible,Jquery is client side for loop in server side. so you can use One javascript or jquery function and use ajax to make this functionalities.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can try like this

    html

     <div class="table-responsive" id="DivTable">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="tbl">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>Age</td>
                            <td>DOB</td>
                            <td>Salary</td>
                            <td>Industry</td>
                            <td>Action</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="dtEmployeeDetails">

                </table>
            </div>

javascript

function GetEmployeeDetails() {
            var EmployeeArray = [];
            $("#dtEmployeeDetails").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetEmployeeDetails", "Employee")',
                dataType: 'json',
                //data: JSON.stringify({ id: '2' }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {

                        EmployeeArray[key] = '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + val.Name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + val.DateofBirth + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + val.Age + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + Industry + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + val.Salary + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + '<a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" title="Edit" id="' + val.EmpID + '" onclick="EditEmployeeDetails(this.id);">' + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;' +
                         '<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Delete" id="' + val.EmpID + '" onclick="DeleteEmployeeDetails(this.id);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td></tr>';
                    });

                    $("#dtEmployeeDetails").html(EmployeeArray.join(""));
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        $("#dtEmployeeDetails").append('<td colspan="6" class="text-center">No Record Found.</td>');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.It is very helpful.